# Asp.Net + Docker + Mysql -> MySqlException: Table 'calendario.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to "dockerize" my webserver. It was working fine running normaly, but I can't make it work with docker-compose.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TokenLabCalendar/TokenLabCalendar.csproj", "TokenLabCalendar/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TokenLabCalendar/TokenLabCalendar.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TokenLabCalendar"
RUN dotnet build "TokenLabCalendar.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TokenLabCalendar.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TokenLabCalendar.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  tokenlabcalendar:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tokenlabcalendar
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TokenLabCalendar/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DBHOST:mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    container_name: calendariodb
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dbvol:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
volumes:
  appbuild:
  dbvol:
```

Every time I make a request to de database I got this error. There is no table in the database.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table
>   'calendario.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table
>   'calendario.AspNetUsers' doesn't exist

I don't know if I need to rerun the migration and update the database before it runs. Any help?